# Why is String.matches returning false in Java?

Tags: java, regex

```
if("test%$@*)$(%".matches("[^a-zA-Z\\.]"))
    System.exit(0);

if("te/st.txt".matches("[^a-zA-Z\\.]"))
    System.exit(0);
```

The program isn't exiting even though the regexes should be returning true. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: If you think it should be returning true, your regex is not doing what you think it's doing. Please tell us what you think it should be doing so we can tell you where you've gone wrong.

Comment: Another wild guess here. But are you meaning to use `^` to mean the begining of the line? If so you are doing it wrong.

Comment: ever tried 'if(matcher.find() == true) return matcher.group(0);'

Comment: This behavior of Java's `String.matches()` does not seem intuitive because in Perl you can do `perl -e '$target_str = "the string"; print $target_str =~ /the/'` and the match is positive. The command returns 1, which equates to `true`. This is something that always gets me in Java and I have to keep referring to support to remember how `String.matches()` works in Java.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`matches` returns `true` only if regex matches *entire string*.

In your case your regex represents only *one* character that is not `a-z`, `A-Z` or `.`.

I suspect that you want to check if string *contains* one of these special characters which you described in regex. In that case surround your regex with `.*` to let regex match entire string. Oh, and you don't have to escape `.` inside character class `[.]`.

```
if ("test%$@*)$(%".matches(".*[^a-zA-Z.].*")) {
    //string contains character that is not in rage a-z, A-Z, or '.'
```

---

BUT if you care about performance you can use `Matcher#find()` method which

1. can return `true` the moment it will find substring containing match for regex. This way application will not need to check rest of the text, which saves us more time the longer remaining text is.
2. Will not force us to constantly build Pattern object each time `String#matches(regex)` is called, because we can create Pattern once and reuse it with different data.

Demo:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z\\.]");

Matcher m = p.matcher("test%$@*)$(%");
if(m.find())
    System.exit(0);

//OR with Matcher inlined since we don't really need that variable
if (p.matcher("test%$@*)$(%").find())
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 13):

`x.matches(y)` is equivalent to

```
Pattern.compile(y).matcher(x).matches()
```

and requires the whole string `x` to match the regex `y`.  If you just want to know if there is *some substring* of `x` that matches `y` then you need to use `find()` instead of `matches()`:

```
if(Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z.]").matcher("test%$@*)$(%").find())
    System.exit(0);
```

Alternatively you could reverse the sense of the test:

```
if(!"test%$@*)$(%".matches("[a-zA-Z.]*"))
```

by providing a pattern that matches the strings that are allowed rather than the characters that aren't, and then seeing whether the test string *fails* to match this pattern.

Comment: Accurate, concise and complete. Nice job. +1

Answer (score 2):

You obtain always false because the `matches()` method returns `true` only when the pattern matches the full string.